# Convert zend paginator to array

Tags: arrays, zend-framework, object, zend-paginator

i have used zend pagination in my controller action.it returns zend paginator object that is in my controller its like this

```
$this->view->paginator=$paginator;
```

in my view i am doing so to iterate

```
 foreach($this->paginator as $record){
   <?php echo $record['column_name1'];?>
   <?php echo $record['column_name2'];?>
 }
```

i need the first row of this paginator that is i want to convert this to simple ARRAY so
that i easily get what i need ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($this->paginator as $key=>$record){
if($key == 0){
 $var1 = $record['column_name1']; //save what u need
 $var2 = $record['column_name2'];
 }
 else{
     break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because [Zend_Paginator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.paginator.html) implements [IteratorAggregate](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php), you can simply use [`iterator_to_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php):

```
$array = iterator_to_array($paginator);
```

PS: `iterator_to_array()` was introduced in PHP v5.1.0

Comment: This is always empty while  the paginator never is.